# Use settings.bundle of custom framework in application

Tags: ios, objective-c, settings.bundle

I am creating a framework for iOS applications. I need some configurable parameters from end users at run time like key, specific set of characters or something else.

These things will be used in my framework not in the application. So I have created Settings.bundle for my framework and I want that whosoever uses this framework will have in-app settings that I desire and have created in that framework project.

Is there a way I can do this?

Answer (score 4):

It's up to hosting app to include such params in Settings. There is no way to enforce the app using your framework to include your params in app settings. From the framework perspective config params should be included in public API. For example the key should be argument to your framework initializer.

Comment: So there is no way other I can add in-app settings using framework?

Comment: No, as I explained earlier. You can expose your settings through API or through some settings view controller within your framework.

Comment: @RockBalbao If you find my answer correct, please remember to accept it. Thanks!

Comment: I will explore some ways and if I find your answer acceptable I will surely accept it. Thanks.